# Xcode 6.3.2 crashes while submiting app to iTuneconnect

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.3.2. When i try to upload build to iTuneconncet it is crashing every time.  This is crash log of xcode

[image]

Solution : As per @kovpas. I try closing xcode workspace and leave just the organizer and then try to upload. Good new is that it works fine. Thanks @Kovpas

Comment: Try closing your workspace and leave just the organizer open: https://twitter.com/zacwest/status/611245608045707265

Comment: Export your archive as an iPA for iOS App Store Deployment. Then use the Application Loader to submit to the AppStore. It might work or give you a hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: While uploading new build to iTunesConnect we always face network issue. Network connection is lost or facing TIME_OUT while during upload with Xcode. Application Loader has become the only option to upload build to iTunesConnect.

Comment: Something has changed @iTunesConnect end i guess. I successfully submitted 2 apps yesterday with Xcode ( same build as above ) yesterday and no issues. Today seeing exactly same error!!!!!.

Comment: @kovpas please add separate answer so people could vote for it because it really helps. I faced same problem today and submitted app to iTunes only after closing project.

Answer (score 2):

Try closing your workspace and leave just the organizer open:

https://twitter.com/zacwest/status/611245608045707265

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same crash multiple times while I was submitting my App today. Finally I used "Application Loader" and it worked like charm. Export your archive as .ipa from XCode and upload using "Application Loader".